# Set List data for property from other function in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

---

I have class ***News***. Each news has ***Related news*** get from

> function **GetRelated**(News news) **return** List< News>

I create ***NewsTagsCommodityViewModel*** to store News and RelatedNews

```
public class NewsTagsCommodityViewModel
{
    public News News { get; set; }
    public List<News> RelatedNews { get; set; }
}
public class NewsDao
{
    //....
    List<News> GetRelated(News news)
    {
          //....
          return res;
    }

    public IEnumerable<NewsTagsCommodityViewModel> ListAllNews()
    {
        var model = db.News.Where(s => s.Status)
                        .Select(s => new NewsTagsCommodityViewModel
                        {
                            News = s,
                            RelatedNews = GetRelated(s)
                        });
        return model.OrderByDescending(x => x.News.CreatedDate);
    }
}
```

When call ListAllNews(), It throw exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Data.Entity.News] GetRelated(Data.Entity.News)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

---

### How to fix this problem?

Code for News

```
public partial class News
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string MetaTitle { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "ntext")]
        public string ContentHtml { get; set; }

        [StringLength(250)]
        public string Images { get; set; }

        [StringLength(250)]
        public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }

        public string MetaDescription { get; set; }

        public bool Status { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string RelatedNews { get; set; }

        public long? CategoryID { get; set; }

        public int? CommodityID { get; set; }

        public int? ViewCount { get; set; }

        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Tags { get; set; }

        public bool UpTopNew { get; set; }

        public bool UpTopHot { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1000)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2)]
        public string LangCode { get; set; }

        public long? RefID { get; set; }
    }
```

---

implementation of **GetRelated()** method.

```
private List<News> GetRelated(News news)
        {
            var listChild = new RouteDao().GetChildrents((int)news.CommodityID);
            var data = db.News.Where(s => s.Status && s.LangCode == news.LangCode).ToList()
                              .Where(s => (s.CommodityID == (int)news.CommodityID) || listChild.Any(x => x.ID == s.CommodityID) || s.CategoryID == news.CategoryID);
            return ListEntityHelpper.PickRandom(data.Where(x => x.ID != news.ID).ToArray(), 3);
        }
```

Comment: Please provide a code for `News` class and implementation of `GetRelated()` method.

Comment: I'm just update post with code for *News* and  *GetRelated()*

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server or whatever data storage you are using does not know what `GetRelated()` is, so it can not map it to SQL query. You can either combine your queries (which is preferable) or add related news to the model after you have fetched news.

Answer (score 0):

I get this exception, because function **GetRelated()** created in class `NewsDao()` not in SQL Server.

I fix it by change:

```
 public IEnumerable<NewsTagsCommodityViewModel> ListAllNews()
 {
        var model = db.News.Where(s => s.Status)
                        .Select(s => new NewsTagsCommodityViewModel
                        {
                            News = s,
                            RelatedNews = GetRelated(s)
                        });
        return model.OrderByDescending(x => x.News.CreatedDate);
 }
```

To:

```
public IEnumerable<NewsTagsCommodityViewModel> ListAllNew()
{
    var model = db.News.Where(s => s.Status)
                    .Select(s => new NewsTagsCommodityViewModel
                    {
                        News = s
                    }).ToList();
    model.ForEach(s => s.RelatedNews = GetRelated(s.News));
    return model.OrderByDescending(x => x.News.CreatedDate);
}
```

==> but this way loop 2 times `model` => performance is not good.

---

Maybe has better way to resolve it!

Comment: If you don't have huge data, this approach is fine. `ToList()` will bring the data in-memory and then you are able to use your custom function. But if data is huge, then you need to write the login in SQL and return only the relevant data.